# How many counts are required to estimate a mean to a certain precision?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, mean

I have been photographing bubbles arriving at a fluid surface. The photographs are obtained at rate of one image per minute. Given that the frame of the image is always the same size and the source of bubbles is assumed to be constant how many images will I have to count to obtain an estimate of the mean number of bubbles per image to a precision of 5%? I am assuming that the number of bubbles per image is poisson distributed and a quick look at the images suggests I have around 5-20 bubbles per image.

Comment: With *what percentage confidence* that the sample mean is within 5% of the population value?

Comment: Hi Glen, say 95%. Something which sprang to mind recalling my school stats is the rule Sigma = sqrt(N). So a very rough estimate might be: 100/5=20; 20^2=400. I guess this means I need to count images until I reach 400 bubbles to reach within 5% of the population mean? I suspect that is wrong but I do not know of a more rigorous approach.

Comment: Ok so now I think I am getting somewhere. Assuming it is correct to use 1.96 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96) for the 95% confidence interval- no doubt other confidence intervals are available... Then the 95% confidence interval is λ±1.96√(λ/n) where λ is the sample mean and n is the number of observations. I can then work out how large n needs to be to get within 5%.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry, I wrote my answer about half an hour ago but then couldn't get online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be assuming the rate of bubbles is constant across images.

If we do that, then you want that a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ CI for $\mu$ is $< 0.05\mu$.

$\text{se}(\hat{\mu}) = \sqrt{\mu/n}$

For a 95% interval, approximately $1.96 \sqrt{\mu/n} = .05 \mu$ ;

approximating again: $2 \sqrt{\mu/n} < .05 \mu$

i.e.

$n>\mu/(.025^2 \mu^2)$

$n>1600/\mu$

if $\mu$ is 5 that's 320 images

if $\mu$ is 10 that's 160 images

if $\mu$ is 20 that's 80 images

The more uncertainty you have about your pilot estimate of $\mu$, the more you should assume that 
$\mu$ is lower than your estimate.

If your estimate itself is from a sample, you can take that (the uncertainty in the estimate) into account.

Check: if $\mu$ is 10 then a sample of 160 should get you 1520-1680 bubbles (about 95% of the time). The estimate of $\mu$ would be between 9.5 and 10.5 95% of the time. Looks about right.

Comment: An excellent confirmation of the conclusion I had come to. Thanks.

Comment: Just as an edit though would it not be 1/0.05^2 or n>400/µ rather than 1/0.025^2 (1600) to be within 5%?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you follow the calculation in my "check"? Where do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I agree with the process although it is not clear to me why you use 0.025^2. I would have used 0.05^2 here. I suspect I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Ah I think I get it- the 0.025 is clearly 0.05/2 because the 5% value is two-tailed. Is that correct?

Comment: Correction: the factor of 2 is because I rounded up 1.96 to 2 (deliberately, since you're approximating); not because it's two tailed. The unrounded calculation is $[1/(0.05/1.96)^2]/\mu$

Comment: Ah yes of course. So obvious when you think about it. Thanks again.